# Siri parameter resolved with NeedsValue is taking the user to the main app

Tags: swift, siri, sirikit, sirishortcuts

I am working on an app that is incorporating Siri with custom intents and configurable & resolvable parameters, but I am seeing some unexpected behavior and wondering if anyone has seen this.

When a parameter is resolved with “needsValue” in spotlight it will continue in the main app, I am expecting it to prompt the user for the value needed. In the Shortcuts app the shortcut runs as expected and prompts the user for the parameter value.

Step-by-Step if anyone wants to give it a shot or check with their project: 
Start with a project that includes Sirikit and parameters.
Enable configurable & resolvable for a parameter
Resolve the parameter with “needsValue” in the intentHandler.
Run the shortcut in spotlight

Expected result: Siri would prompt the user for the needed value for the parameter

Actual result: The user is taken to the main app

I was also able to reproduce this in the SoupChef sample project Apple provides by adding a new String type parameter and resolved that method with .needsValue in OrderSoupIntentHandler.

In the intentHandler the settings I have are:

Widgets: ✅ Intent is eligible for widgets

Configurable in Shortcuts: ⧠ Intent is user-configurable in the shortcuts app and Add to Siri

Suggestions: ✅ Intent is eligible for Siri Suggestions

Any help would be very appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Apple has answered my feedback assistant submission and identified a potential fix via an OS update